# My component returns undefined in react hook form controller

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form

I can't figure out how to add an array from a component to my form. When I submit the form I get undefined. You need to use a controller, but it doesn't return anything. Help me to understand. I added an example to the github repository. I will be glad for any help

https://github.com/NikolayMirov/form-step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Controller
      control={control}
      name="parameters"
      render={({field}) => <Step name={field.name} value={field.value} onChange={field.onChange}/>}
    />
```

Then in your Step component when value change call `props.onChange` and pass the array.

```
const handleMonthChange = (month: string, idx: number) => {
const newStateArr = state.map((item) => {
  if (idx !== item.id) return item;
  return { ...item, month: Number(month) };
});

setState(newStateArr);
props.onChange({
     target: { 
         name: props.name,
         value:newStateArr
     }
   });
};
```

Comment: Hey!  That helped! Thank you so much for taking the time to help figure it out! Such people are very valuable in life, good luck to you!